# Including C# files when compiling programmatically from a string

Tags: c#, compilation, codedom

I was previously exporting CodeDOM CompilationUnits to files, and then reading those files back in to compile them using a CSharpCodeProvider. Today I refactored the code so that the CodeDOM is exported to a String:

```
public static string compileToString(CodeCompileUnit cu){
        // Generate the code with the C# code provider.
        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            IndentedTextWriter tw = new IndentedTextWriter(sw, "    ");

            // Generate source code using the code provider.
            provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(cu, tw,
                new CodeGeneratorOptions());

            tw.Close();

            return sw.ToString ();
        }   
    }
```

And then changed the compilation so that it uses CompileFromSource:

```
public static Assembly BuildAssemblyFromString(string code){
        Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider provider = 
           new CSharpCodeProvider();
        ICodeCompiler compiler = provider.CreateCompiler();
        CompilerParameters compilerparams = new CompilerParameters();
        compilerparams.GenerateExecutable = false;
        compilerparams.GenerateInMemory = true;

        compilerparams.CompilerOptions = "/nowarn:162";
        string[] files = new string[]{"TemplateAesthetic.cs"};

        CompilerResults results = 
           compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerparams, code);
        if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder("Compiler Errors :\r\n");
            foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors )
            {
                errors.AppendFormat("Line {0},{1}\t: {2}\n", 
                       error.Line, error.Column, error.ErrorText);
                Debug.Log (error.ErrorText);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return results.CompiledAssembly;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Thanks to Maarten for noticing: the problem is that I need to include a real file (TemplateAesthetic.cs) in the compilation process, but this compilation happens from a string. Can you do a mixed compilation in this way using CompileAssemblyFromSource?

Answer (score 1):

### Initial answer:

As far as I can see, your variable `string[] files` is not used anywhere. Do they need to be added to the compiler parameters somewhere?

### Update:

The method you are using actually accepts a `params string[] sources` which means you can give multiple strings to the method. So the solution would be to read the files from disk into memory (strings), and create an array with *all* sources, and give that array to the method.

Change this:

```
CompilerResults = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerparams, code);
```

To this:

```
var fileContents = files.Select(x => File.ReadAllText(x)).ToList();
fileContents.Add(code);
CompilerResults results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(
    compilerparams, 
    fileContents
);
```

Sorry, no time to test it.

Comment: Hah. You're completely right. I might need to edit the question then as there's a new problem now: can you add normal files to a compileassemblyfromsource call? Perhaps a compilerparam as you suggest.